# Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings endpoint

Tags: salesforce, twilio

I'm unable to send an SMS via Twilio API. I got the exception below:

> **ERROR :** Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings endpoint: url

```
global class SampleSMSTest {
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void testsms() {
        try {
            String account = 'xxxxxxxxx';
            String token = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
            TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);
            Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String> {
                'To' => '+91953835xxxx',
                'From' => '+1920569xxxx', // twilio registered number
                'Body' => 'Hello there!'
            };
            TwilioMessage message = client.getAccount().getMessages().create(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Main error==========>' + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like Salesforce APEX code.  Anytime you want to call an external URL from Salesforce, you need to set the URL as a safe remote site. The error message tells you exactly where to go in SF. Add the Twilio URL "api.twilio.com" to the list.

Comment: Yes it Salesforce Apex,Can you tell me Where should I add the twilio URL

Answer (score 8):

Add the Twilio URL in sandbox as following path

```
Administration Setup  > Security Controls > Remote Site Settings > click "**New Remote Site**" button.
```

I have re-solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

On my salesforce lightning page, I do these steps.

1. Click 'gear icon' on top-right side of your page. Click 'setup'
2. Click 'Security -> Remote Site settings'
3. On 'Remote Site Settings' page, click 'new remote site' button
4. Add your remote site URL