# Unable to send a sms by using twilio

Tags: salesforce, twilio, apex

I have salesforce apex class; in that class I am unable to send an SMS via the twilio api.
It executes properly, but didn't send any message. The code  [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24290617) is my post.

Can someone tell me why it is not sending an sms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are sending to an Indian number, messages might not be delivered if it is on the national DND list, you can check the numbers status [here](http://www.nccptrai.gov.in/nccpregistry/search.misc).

If your number is indeed registered we will not be able to deliver to it until its removed.

Comment: Yes now it is working,I need to receive the sms via twilio api in salesforce.How to receive the SMS?

Comment: @SeekTom - How Microsoft and Google like apps are able to send SMS even when our numbers are in DND?

Comment: Hi Santosh, I suspect they have a transactional messaging route within India that allows them to send messages to customers on the DND list. Transactional messaging is restricted to certain content such as pin/verification codes.